# Can't connect to WebSocket Nginx in my Django app chat on deployment I'm use to Nginx and Supervisor

Tags: django, nginx, websocket, deployment

I'm trying to use WebSocket for my Django project. I have an app chat in  Django  but I can't get it to connect in deployment, these are my config files and the error. I'm using nginx and supervisor in Ubuntu 18.04

Error:

[image: error in browser]

## settings.py

```
    from InclusionEducativa.settings import *
    import os
    import dj_database_url
    from django.urls import reverse_lazy
    
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    SECRET_KEY = '0r9u3z=w6j2mq$vbus@(ppx5%f+c63pgmsnum10=!_jvl7i@2h'
    DEBUG = True
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
    ADMINS = [('Jafet', 'jafetandres@hotmail.com')]
    
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'InclusionEducativa.Apps.GestionSistema',
        'InclusionEducativa.Apps.AppDocente',
        'InclusionEducativa.Apps.AppRepresentante',
        'InclusionEducativa.Apps.AppExperto',
        'InclusionEducativa.Apps.automata',
        'django_chatter',
        'channels',
        'notifications',
        'InclusionEducativa.Apps.chat'
    ]
    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    
    ]
    ROOT_URLCONF = 'InclusionEducativa.urls'
    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'InclusionEducativa/templates')],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    
                ],
    
            },
        },
    ]
    
    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'InclusionEducativa.wsgi.application'
    ASGI_APPLICATION = 'InclusionEducativa.routing.application'
    
    CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
            'CONFIG': {
                'hosts': [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
            },
    
        },
    }
    
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': 'InclusionEducativa.db',
        }
    }
    
    AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
        },
    ]
    LANGUAGE_CODE = "es-es"
    TIME_ZONE = 'America/Guayaquil'
    USE_I18N = True
    USE_L10N = False
    DATE_FORMAT = "Y-m-d"
    USE_TZ = True
    
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'InclusionEducativa/static/')
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'InclusionEducativa/media')
    DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 10242880
    
    LOGIN_URL = '/gestionsistema/login/'
    LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'index'
    
    AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'GestionSistema.Usuario'
    
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
    EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'jafetgalvez1@gmail.com'
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'kgelhdsd'
    EMAIL_PORT = 587
    EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
    
    SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 0
    SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
    SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
    SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
    SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'
    SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
```

## routing.py

```
    from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
    from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
    from InclusionEducativa.Apps.chat import routing
    
    application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
        'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                routing.websocket_urlpatterns
            )
        ),
    })
```

## routing.py  Inside app Chat

```
    from django.urls import re_path
    
    from . import consumers
    
    websocket_urlpatterns = [
        re_path(r'^ws/chat/(?P<room_id>[^/]+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer),
    ]
```

## chat.html

```
    <script>
        var room_id = "{{ room.id }}";
        var username = "{{ username }}";
        var chatSocket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(
            'ws://' + window.location.host +
            '/ws/chat/' + room_id + '/');
    
    
        chatSocket.onopen = function (e) {
            console.log('Websocket connected')
            fetchMessages();
        }
    
        chatSocket.onmessage = function (e) {
            var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
            if (data['command'] === 'messages') {
                for (let i = 0; i < data['messages'].length; i++) {
                    createMessage(data['messages'][i]);
                }
            } else if (data['command'] === 'new_message') {
                createMessage(data['message']);
            }
        };
    
        chatSocket.onclose = function (e) {
            console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
        };
    
        document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').onkeyup = function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {  // enter, return
                document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').click();
            }
        };
    
        document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').onclick = function (e) {
            var messageInputDom = document.querySelector('#chat-message-input');
            var message = messageInputDom.value;
            if (message.replace(/\s/g, "") != "") {
                chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
                    'command': 'new_message',
                    'message': message,
                    'from': username,
                    'room_id': room_id
                }));
            }
    
            messageInputDom.value = '';
        };
    
        function fetchMessages() {
            chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({'command': 'fetch_messages', 'room_id': room_id}));
        }
    
        function createMessage(data) {
            var author = data['author'];
            var msgListTag = document.createElement('div');
            var msgContainer = document.createElement('div');
            var imgContainer = document.createElement('div');
            var msgTime = document.createElement('span');
            var imgTag = document.createElement('img');
            msgContainer.textContent = data.content;
            msgTime.textContent = dateFormatter(data.timestamp);
    
    
            if (author === username) {
                msgListTag.className = 'd-flex justify-content-end mb-4';
                msgContainer.className = 'msg_cotainer_send';
                msgTime.className = 'msg_time';
    
            } else {
                msgListTag.className = 'd-flex justify-content-start mb-4';
                msgContainer.className = 'msg_cotainer';
                msgTime.className = 'msg_time_send';
                imgContainer.className = 'img_cont_msg';
                imgTag.className = 'rounded-circle user_img_msg';
                imgTag.src = data.foto;
    
    
            }
    
            msgListTag.appendChild(imgContainer);
            msgListTag.appendChild(msgContainer);
            msgContainer.appendChild(msgTime);
            imgContainer.appendChild(imgTag);
            document.querySelector('#chat-log').appendChild(msgListTag);
            var element = document.getElementById("chat-log");
            element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight - element.clientHeight;
        }
    </script>
```

## nginx.conf

```
    upstream wsgi_server {
        server unix:/home/inclusion/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
    }
    upstream asgi_server {
        server unix:/home/inclusion/./run/daphne.sock fail_timeout=0;
    }
    server{
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name localhost;
        keepalive_timeout 5;
            client_max_body_size 4G;
        access_log /home/inclusion/logs/nginx.access.log; 
        error_log /home/inclusion/logs/nginx.error.log; 
        location /static {
            access_log off;
                alias /home/inclusion/inclusioneducativa/static;
            } 
        location /media {
                access_log off;
                alias /home/inclusion/inclusioneducativa/media;
            } 
            location / {
            try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
            }
        location /ws/ {
                try_files $uri @proxy_to_ws;
                }
        location @proxy_to_ws {
                    proxy_pass http://asgi_server;
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                    proxy_redirect off;
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                    }
            location @proxy_to_app {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://wsgi_server;      
            }
        }
```

## supervisor.conf

```
    [program:inclusion]
    command=/home/inclusion/bin/gunicorn_start
    user=inclusion         
    autostart=true
    autorestart=true
    redirect_stderr=true
    stdout_logfile=/home/inclusion/logs/gunicorn-error.log
    
    [program:serverinterface]
    directory=/home/inclusion/inclusioneducativa
    command=/home/inclusion/./bin/daphne -u /home/inclusion/./run/daphne.sock       InclusionEducativa.asgi:application
    autostart=true
    autorestart=true
    stopasgroup=true
    user=inclusion
    stdout_logfile =/home/inclusion/logs/daphne-error.log
```

Comment: Have a look at the logs for the WS server, maybe it crashed. Also have a look at the Supervisor logs to ensure it started the WS server correctly, and whether it had to perform any restarts.